Printing Tree structure from two lists
I have a pandas DataFrame of two columns A and B as below:



A
B




process1
process2


process2
process3


process1
process4


process1
process5


procesa14
process15


process5
process6


process14
process16


process16
process17


process16
process18


process14
process19



I want to print a tree of parent/child relation based on below:

If any process in col 'A' does not appear in col 'B' then it will be a root of tree. In this case process1 and process14 does not appear in 'B' so they are the root

process1 (root) created process2, process4 and process5 and process2 created process3 and process5 created process6.

process14 (root) created process15, process16, process19 and process16 created process17 and process18.


So the desired output should be like below:
|_process1
    |_process2
        |_process3
    |_process4
    |_process5
        |_process6


|_process14
    |_process15
    |_process16
        |_process17
        |_process18
    |_process19

I converted both columns into lists:
list1_a = ['process1','process2','process1','process1','process5','process14','process14','process16','process16','process14']

list1_b = ['process2','process3','process4','process5','process6 ','process15','process16','process17','process18','process19']

But I not able to create a good structure which creates this parent/child relation and then I can print out.

What about this:
def build_tree(parents, children):
    tree = {}
    for parent, child in zip(parents, children):
        if parent not in tree:
            tree[parent] = []
        tree[parent].append(child)
    return tree

def print_tree(tree, node, level=0):
    print("  " * level + "|_"+ node)
    if node in tree:
        for child in tree[node]:
            print_tree(tree, child, level + 1)

list1_a = ['process1','process2','process1','process1','process5','process14','process14','process16','process16','process14']
list1_b = ['process2','process3','process4','process5','process6 ','process15','process16','process17','process18','process19']

# Build the tree structure
tree = build_tree(list1_a, list1_b)

# Find the roots (processes not appearing in list1_b)
roots = set(list1_a) - set(list1_b)

# Print the tree structure
for root in roots:
    print_tree(tree, root)



thank you. that was great and simple. I was overthinking : )

We can build this using collections.defaultdict and print the folder structure.
from collections import defaultdict

class TreeBuilder:
    def __init__(self, parents, children):
        self.tree = defaultdict(set)
        self.roots = set(parents)
        for parent, child in zip(parents, children):
            self.tree[parent].add(child)
            self.roots.discard(child)

    def print_tree(self):
        for root in sorted(self.roots):
            self._print_tree_helper(root)

    def _print_tree_helper(self, current_node, level=0):
        print("  " * level + "L" + current_node)
        children = sorted(self.tree.get(current_node, set()))
        for child in children:
            self._print_tree_helper(child, level + 1)

We can execute this class as follows:
list1_a = ['process1','process2','process1','process1','process5','process14','process14','process16','process16','process14']
list1_b = ['process2','process3','process4','process5','process6 ','process15','process16','process17','process18','process19']

tree_builder = TreeBuilder(list1_a, list1_b)
tree_builder.print_tree()

The resulting output is
Lprocess1
  Lprocess2
    Lprocess3
  Lprocess4
  Lprocess5
    Lprocess6
Lprocess14
  Lprocess15
  Lprocess16
    Lprocess17
    Lprocess18
  Lprocess19

